# Distribution density for k-th independent variable

Tags: probability

The problem:

- There are $n$ points uniformly and independently distributed on the segment $\left(0,1\right)$.
- The points are sorted ascending.
- Calculate distribution density of $k$-th point's coordinate.

I calculated ( and checked experimentally ) that for $z \in \left(0,1\right)$ probability for the $k$-th point to be less than $z$ is

$\displaystyle P_{k} \equiv
\mathrm{P}\left\{x_k < z\right\} =
\sum_{i = k}^{n}\binom{n}{i}z^{i}\left(1 - z\right)^{n - i}$

The desired density is

1. $\displaystyle \frac{dP_k}{dz} =
   \sum_{i = k}^{n}\binom{n}{i}z^{i - 1}\left(1 - z\right)^{n - i - 1}\left(i - zn\right)$

and ( this is my question ) somehow the latter appears to be equal to

2. $\displaystyle\frac{dP_k}{dz} =
   z^{k - 1}k\left(1 - z\right)^{n - k}\binom{n}{k}$

How do you get $2.$ from $1.$ ?.

Comment: The keyword for what you are looking for is "order statistics".

Answer (score 1):

Using induction (base is $k=n$, and then decrement $k$ in induction junction), one can prove that (1) <=> (2).